# Returning XML from an AJAX requestfor RSS Feed

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

I have a website where I'd like to make a request to the BBC RSS feed to return the latest news. The problem is I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

This is my code:

```
var url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml';

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    contentType : 'text/xml',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

### Edit

Here is my code on my server, as suggested by the answers below:

```
    public XmlDocument callBBCFeed()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(result);

        return doc;
    }
```

I then call this in my JS code like so:

```
    var url = 'http://myServer/Global/callBBCFeed';



    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'xml',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But I get the Same Origin Policy Error

Answer (score 1):

Check your $.ajax call: `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

RSS is XML. Since your call expects retrieving JSON, `<` is an ilegal character, isn't it?

Read jQuery $.ajax documentation and look for "dataType" option:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

*UPDATE*

Based on some comment that you added to some other answer, it seems that your initial problem is *cross-domain requesting*.

Best solution for that is do that cross-domain call from the server-side (using server code in ASP.NET C#/VB or whatever, PHP, Perl, Ruby...) and jQuery will call your server handler to retrieve that RSS feed, so it's not a cross-domain request anymore.

Comment: I tried dataType of `xml` but I get the Same Origin Policy Restriction, that's why I tried `jsonp`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a cross domain AJAX request to an XML resource. That cannot work due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction.

You are in a complete contradiction here:

```
dataType : 'jsonp'
```

and yet sending a request to a XML resource.

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which allows for cross domain AJAX calls is something entirely different. It represents a JSON response wrapped in a javascript function that might look like this:

```
someFunctionName({"foo":"bar", "baz":"bazzy"})
```

If the remote server doesn't support JSONP, you will have to write a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge between yours and the remote domain to fetch the XML file. Then use jQuery AJAX to send a request to your script.

I would recommend you reading the following [jQuery cross domain AJAX guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) for different techniques that could be used.

Comment: Thats why I tried to set the dataType to `jsonp`. Is there anyway to resolve this then?

Comment: But you can set the dataType to jsonp if the remote server returns JSONP, otherwise it doesn't make any sense. There are different workarounds if the remote server doesn't support JSONP. I have linked to a guide that you might read. But the most reliable way, if the remote domain that you are scraping doesn't allow for such calls is to write a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge. You should understand that if the remote server doesn't support JSONP or CORS your choices are very limited at this stage to consume it from javascript.

Comment: Ok.. I've made a method on my server which makes the request, I then call that like so: `var url = 'http://myServer/Global/callBBCFeed';` and I get the Same Origin Policy error

Comment: If it is on your server, don't use absolute urls. Use relative ones: `var url = '/callBBCFeed';`.