# Why calling RSS feeds from ajax not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, rss

I am trying to code [this](http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/sports/football.xml)  RSS feed of football.

but when I am calling it, its giving some error as below

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/sports/football.xml.
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

What is the problem with my call??

My code for the call is as under

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/sports/football.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
});

function xmlParser(xml){
    console.log(xml);

    var xmlcode='';

    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
        xmlcode+="<li>"+$(this).find('title').text()+"</li>";
    });

    $('.headline-ul').html(xmlcode);
}
```

Is there anything else needed to use that field?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below links which may help you in resolving the issue

[Displaying Feed Content using jQuery](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/displaying-feed-content-using-jquery.html)

[Returning XML from an AJAX requestfor RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340020/returning-xml-from-an-ajax-requestfor-rss-feed)

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) AJAX Requests Between jQuery And Node.js](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm)